# IIS 7 css updating in .net website

Tags: html, css, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have made changes to a css file in a mvc5 website that is deployed on IIS 7. I used the bundle configuration to setup the css files in the website so the css has been cached as /website/content/css?v=Bz3KZjU_pdOm2wAVr7z_ylCuQzQDs1O8N6pV4cvXc_Q1. Now the changes I have made on the css included in that bundle are not being shown in the browser. I have tried the following with no effect.

- reset IIS
- delete temporary internet files
- touch the web.config file
- recycle app pool
- refreshing the browser using f5

I do not know what else to try..

Comment: did you try to use the development tools of your browser ? In the  network tab, check the HTTP status when you get the bundle. Generally the cache is disable when using dev tools.

Comment: in network tab it says 304 not modified. when it has been

Comment: so the bundle is not up to date. Did you use minify version ? It could be the problem according to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158933/asp-net-bundling-bundle-not-updating-after-included-file-has-changed-returns)

Comment: no i didnt use the minified version

Comment: Sorry i did have a minified version. I deleted that and problem went away. thanksvery much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in release the bundle uses the minified versions so update or delete the minified versions to see if it's help.
See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158933/asp-net-bundling-bundle-not-updating-after-included-file-has-changed-returns) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this may happen, You have to forces clear your cache and cookie.
There are some way to forces clear your cookie

1. Start browser InPrivate browsing.
2. In developer tool(Pressing F12) choice Cache->Always refresh from server this may some time.
3. In developer tool script tab press start debugging.