# ASP.NET MVC4 Bundling not cache busting when file changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I've read thru answers to this question: [ASP.NET Bundling - Bundle not updating after included file has changed (returns 304 not modified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158933/asp-net-bundling-bundle-not-updating-after-included-file-has-changed-returns)

However, none of the answers fix or match with what I am seeing.

First, I am able to reproduce my issue on Windows 10 and Windows 2012 server.

I have built my project in release mode, changed debug=false in web.config.

I have updated my project to the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization NuGet package, version 1.1.3

My bundle setup looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
   BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mybundle")
      .Include("~/Views/User/UserSearch.js")
      .Include("~/Views/User/UserEdit.js")
   );

   ...
}
```

Neither of the files listed in the bundle (UserSearch.js, UserEdit.js) have .min versions in the directory or anywhere else.

The end of my User.cshtml file looks like this:

```
@section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/otherstuff")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mybundle")
   <script type="text/javascript" src="AnotherFile.js"></script>
}
```

All that said, when I view the page, I see a request for the bundle come thru:

`https://local/bundles/mybundle?v=wlen6W7mg528CIKzW0x3ewQacQ6mf8wyin1XGaXoonQ1`

I then make a change to my UserSearch.js file by adding an `alert('hi');` line at the top.

At this point, if I refresh the page, I am *expecting* the v= querystring parameter to change, and the alert box to appear.  But it does not.

If I recycle the site or IIS, and visit the page again, I get the alert box.

Is cache-busting supposed to work on the fly without re-compile or recycling?

Are there any other things that could be interfering with either the bundler not recognizing the file change OR the @Scripts.Render() not writing out a new token?

Comment: Not a complete answer (because it assumes this does work as you expect, which it apparently doesn't), but more info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317391/how-to-force-bundlecollection-to-flush-cached-script-bundles-in-mvc4/12324888#12324888