# Bootstrap update only working on Debug configuration (Visual Studio)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

So I recently update from bootstrap 2 to bootstrap 4. I then changed the syntax, grids and such. The website was running/building fine in debug, however, when it comes to release, it won't work. It can build without errors, but when I run it, it seems like the site has the new syntax and classes (the code running is the one i changed) but bootstrap is still at v.2. I checked multiple times, there are no bootstrap 2 files left, nor any cdn references. I can see it still is running bootstrap 2 by changing classes from col-12 to, say span12. It works fine in debug, but not in release. Any clue why ?

Also, the site is running Asp.NET Core MVC Razor.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache? And how are you referencing bootstrap? Did you add it to your project manually, or are you using a package manager?

Comment: I did clear cache. I'm referencing it using bundles, no package manager.

Comment: Maybe an issue with the bundles not getting rebuilt in Release mode? This could be helpful: [asp.net bundling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158933/asp-net-bundling-bundle-not-updating-after-included-file-has-changed-returns)

Comment: I found that enabling the DEBUG constant while in release mode makes it work... However, I only have 2 #if DEBUG, which I tried removing/changing, but that didn't fix anything... I'll continue trying to figure out the problem...

Comment: Can you share the code of Index.cshtml or Layout.cshtml code where you are referencing the css bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a bundle-ing configuration issue.
Please verify your bundle configuration (App_Start\BundleConfig.cs) and the web.config settings and pertinent web.config transform.
You can find documentation on how to configure your bundles here : [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) (assuming you're not using ASP.NET Core)

For ASP.NET Core it a bit more complicated because you can have multiple ways of doing the budleing. Documentation for it can be found here: [Bundle and minifiy static assets in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x).

However, I think that is pretty probable that the production version of your app is still targeting the old Bootstrap version because of the bundle-ing configuration

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, but I am using .net Core. I edited the main post.

Comment: I've added the link for the ASP.NET Core bundleing documentation

Comment: It ended up working... As the site is pretty big and I didn't write it entirely myself, I wasn't aware but there was something pulling css from the live server instead of local.. Anyway, thanks.